# In Hadoop , how to get the instance of currently running Jobtracker?

Tags: hadoop

I am working on a Monitoring Tool for Hadoop. I need to get the currently running jobtracker. How can I get that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'get the currently running jobtracker' ? With Java API? Or PID is enough?

Comment: I want to get an instance of the jobTracker so that I can get informations like killed jobs, failed jobs, completed jobs etc. I saw the jobtrakcer.jsp and it is getting the current jobtrakcer by using request.getAttribute("job.tracker") and also found that the infoServer.setAttribute ("job.trakcer") (in jobTrakcer.java ) setting the current jobtracker. When I tried I failed since it is not available in the context. I think there must be some way to get the current jobtracker's instance. JobTracker.startTracker(conf) which is returning a jobtracker instance but it restarts the jobtracker.Thanks

Comment: OK, but do you do this with Java API? In other words: what programming language do you want to use?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `<hadoopdir>/conf/mapred-site.xml` configuration file.

In this file, you should find a `<property>` that has a `<name>` of `mapred.job.tracker`:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>node5:12345</value>
<property>
```

This tells you what node it is running on and what port it is running on.

If you are looking for any specific information, please elaborate in your original question.

Comment: I want to get an instance of the jobTracker so that I can get informations like killed jobs, failed jobs, completed jobs etc. I saw the jobtrakcer.jsp and it is getting the current jobtrakcer by using request.getAttribute("job.tracker") and also found that the infoServer.setAttribute ("job.trakcer") (in jobTrakcer.java ) setting the current jobtracker. When I tried I failed since it is not available in the context. I think there must be some way to get the current jobtracker's instance. JobTracker.startTracker(conf) which is returning a jobtracker instance but it restarts the jobtracker.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe the closest you can get at this time is using the JobClient class: [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html)

This will allow you to see running jobs, or walk all jobs.